# Intersection Lights

Tags: three.js, light

Description of the problem

Hello, I use hemisphere light and pointlight and have trouble with intersection shadows
http://joxi.ru/1A5636HKpy3XrE

This is problem on three.js or in my code?

Three.js version

- [Three.js] ^0.84.0

Browser

- [x] Chrome

OS

- [X] Windows

Hardware Requirements (graphics card, VR Device, ...)

intel I7 4650
nvidea GTX 970

Comment: play around with the shadow map bias https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow

Comment: I try, but haven't result

Comment: then you need to post some code or even better a fiddle.